# C# asp.net - get windows user login account on deploy server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using C# asp.net to get windows login account (domain\username) for login my web automatically. I can get the account correctly when run the statement "System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToString()" locally on visual studio. However, after deploying the web page to deploy server, it returns "NT AUTHORITY\IUSR".

Most of the solution I found on internet is to use Windows Authentication instead of Anonymous Authentication. I have tried this solution and a user login window is prompted when run the web. It needs to enter the username and password for the deployed server. However, my windows user login account cannot login to the deploy server. Therefore I cannot run the web on my computer.

I would like to know is it possible to get the window user login account if my window account cannot login to the deploy server?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to enable two Authentication methods. First you have to enable `Windows Authentication` like you already mentioned to pass your credentails automatically to the server (of course only in Intranet).
Additionally you have to activate `ASP.NET Impersonation` to allow the server to use the passed credentials.
The Help tells you why:

> Use ASP.NET Impersonation authentication when you want to run your
>   ASP.NET application under a security context different from the
>   default.

In your `web.config` you have to add the following nodes to your `system.web` node to tell your application to pass your credentials to the server:

```
<identity impersonate="true"/>
<authentication mode="Windows" />
```

Comment: I am sorry that I would like to know how to pass my credentials automatically to the server?

Comment: your windows credentials are passed automatically if you setup your project and server like mentioned above.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion to enable Windows Authentication and ASP.NET Impersonation on IIS and add the two statements on web.config. However, the problem still exists. I need to enter user account and password when run the website but my login user account cannot login to the deploy server.